# Show that $\lim (\sqrt{n^2+1)}-n) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Can't use limit rules as $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ and n are not convergent sequences

Answer (score 3):

The classic approach: write

$$(\sqrt{n^2+1} - n )\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n}$$

Now...

Comment: Ahhh! thanks so much! I think I know where to go from here!